# findById() or findByUuid() don't match and return null with ReactiveMongoRepository and UUID

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, testing, reactive-programming

**I have a microservice that uses ReactiveMongorepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface ISolutionsRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Solutions, UUID> {

    Mono<Solutions> findByUuid(UUID uuid);
```

**And a Document Solutions I try to test with:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Document(collection = "solutions")
public class Solutions {

    @Field(name = "_id")
    @MongoId
    private UUID uuid;

    @Field(name = "user_id")
    private UUID userId;

    @Field(name = "status")
    private String status;
```

...and other fields.

When I try to test it after importing the data to a mongo image in a testcontainer, `findById(uuid)` and `findByUuid(uuid)` return always `null`, never get a match, and I know the documents are well imported because if I do a `findAll()`, I get the proper Solutions that I imported. It also works with `findByStatus(status)`, which returns the proper Solutions document that matches the status.

I know Mongo stores the uuids when I import them as a Binary x04, and at first I had a problm with the conversion between UUID and Binary, but I added a custom converter to the configuration that also tested and was aorking as intended, converting UUID to Binary and viceversa.

I can't figure why `findById` it's not finding any match even though I know the document is properly imported. Also, I have another `ReactiveRepository` for another `Document` class where, instead of importing the dummy data to the mongo image I just create the objects in java and save them through the method in the repository, then the tests match the uuids.

**The test, for reference:**

```java
@DataMongoTest
@Testcontainers
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-test.properties")
@Import(ConvertersConfig.class)
public class SolutionsRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private ISolutionsRepository solutionRepository;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "mongoimport",
            "--uri", container.getReplicaSetUrl("users"),
            "--db", "users",
            "--collection", "solutions",
            "--jsonArray",
            "--file", "solutions.json"
    ).directory(new File("src/test/resources"));

    Process process = processBuilder.start();

   try{
       int exitCode = process.waitFor();

       if (exitCode == 0) {
           System.out.println("Successful import");
       } else {
           System.err.println("Import error");
       }

   }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

private final UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("a75fa943-6bc9-4e62-b1db-d43d15b149c7");

@Test
public void testFindByUuid() {

    System.out.println(uuid);

    System.out.println(solutionRepository.findAll().blockFirst()); //Gives one of the solutions
    System.out.println(solutionRepository.findAll().blockLast()); //Gives one of the solutions
    System.out.println(solutionRepository.findAll().blockFirst().getUuid().getClass()); //The class is properly converted, as I get java.util.UUID here
    System.out.println(solutionRepository.findAll().blockFirst().getUuid()); //Gives the proper UUID

    System.out.println(solutionRepository.findByUuid(uuid).block()); //Returns null

    Mono<Solutions> solutionsFound = solutionRepository.findByUuid(uuid);
    solutionsFound.blockOptional().ifPresentOrElse( //Never present, always go to fail
            solutions -> assertEquals(solutions.getUuid(), uuid),
            () -> fail("Solutions with ID " + uuid + " not found"));

}
```

**And the converters:**

```
@Component
@ReadingConverter
public class BinaryToUUIDConverter implements Converter<Binary, UUID> {

    @Override
    public UUID convert(Binary binary) {
        byte[] bytes = binary.getData();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        long mostSigBits = buffer.getLong();
        long leastSigBits = buffer.getLong();
        return new UUID(mostSigBits, leastSigBits);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@WritingConverter
public class UUIDToBinaryConverter implements Converter<UUID, Binary> {

    @Override
    public Binary convert(UUID uuid) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[16]);
        buffer.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
        buffer.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
        return new Binary(buffer.array());
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I'm loading this:

```json
[
  {
    "_id" : {
      "$uuid" : "a75fa943-6bc9-4e62-b1db-d43d15b149c7"
    },
    "user_id": { "$uuid": "442b8e6e-5d57-4d12-9be2-3ff4f26e7d79"},
    "challenge_id": { "$uuid":"5c1a97e5-1cca-4144-9981-2de1fb73b178"},
    "language_id": { "$uuid": "09fabe32-7362-4bfb-ac05-b7bf854c6e0f"},
    "bookmarked": true,
    "status": "ended",
    "score": 95,
     "solution":[ 
       {
          "_id" :  {
              "$uuid" : "dcacb291-b4aa-4029-8e9b-284c8ca80296"
          },
          "solution_text": "Sed dictum. Proin eget odio. Aliquam vulputate ullamcorper magna. Sed eu eros. Nam consequat dolor vitae dolor. Donec fringilla. Donec"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : {
      "$uuid" : "956c9dbd-2e85-4d68-a75b-9783d83c7f72"
    },
    "user_id": { "$uuid": "c3a92f9d-5d10-4f76-8c0b-6d884c549b1c"},
    "challenge_id": { "$uuid": "7fc6a737-dc36-4e1b-87f3-120d81c548aa"},
    "language_id": { "$uuid": "1e047ea2-b787-49e7-acea-d79e92be3909"},
    "bookmarked": true,
    "status": "ended",
    "score": 95,
    "solution":[
      {
        "_id" : {
          "$uuid" : "dcacb291-b4aa-4029-8e9b-284c8ca80296"
        },
        "solution_text": "Sed dictum. Proin eget odio. Aliquam vulputate ullamcorper magna. Sed eu eros. Nam consequat dolor vitae dolor. Donec fringilla. Donec"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : {
      "$uuid" : "1e8f64e2-6d68-4ae1-9425-8102d0ab61d3"
    },
    "user_id": { "$uuid": "76f906d8-8d02-4a61-892e-83744b685fd2"},
    "challenge_id": { "$uuid": "866853b8-ae7d-4daf-8c82-5e6f653e0fc1"},
    "language_id": { "$uuid": "09fabe32-7362-4bfb-ac05-b7bf854c6e0f"},
    "bookmarked": true,
    "status": "medium",
    "score": 60,
    "solution": [
      {
        "_id" :  {
          "$uuid" : "47fa6202-61d5-4de8-9fa1-6f5e4d82a4a0"
        },
        "solution_text": "Sed dictum. Proin eget odio. Aliquam vulputate ullamcorper magna. Sed eu eros. Nam consequat dolor vitae dolor. Donec fringilla. Donec"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What are you loading?

Comment: I've just edited to show what I'm loading!